# Log4Net - Using on a Single Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I am using Log4Net on a single aspx page - I mean this page doesn't have a web.config and depends on the default machine.config settings. I am trying to use Database logging but nothing is getting logged. I see no exception when I debug through the code. I tried this with a winform app as well but it is still not working. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Here is my code and config file:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net debug="true">   
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="100" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionString value="XXX/>
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO [tblLogs] ([timeoccurred],[calltype],[severity],[message]) VALUES (@timeoccurred, @calltype, @severity, @message)" />

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@timeoccurred"/>
            <dbType value="DateTime"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@calltype"/>
            <dbType value="String"/>
            <size value="20"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%calltype"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@severity"/>
            <dbType value="String"/>
            <size value="50"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@message"/>
            <dbType value="String"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

    </appender>
</log4net>
```

The code is here:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("Log4Net.Config")));
log4net.MDC.Set("calltype", callType);

log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Comment: just to confirm, is that config you pasted inside of Log4Net.Config file? If Yes, you should check whether it exists (as log4net won't complain)

Comment: Have you tried a rolling file appender to ensure that log4net is being correctly configured. Get it working with a rolling file appender then try the db configuration.

Comment: Then try sql profiler to see what SQL it's trying to execute. Check the SQL Server log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standalone configuration file does not need the `configSections` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
   ...
</log4net>
```

---

Some additional advice: Use [thread context](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx) instead of MDC which is deprecated and consider getting your loggers as follows:

```
log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(YourClass));
```

Comment: set the buffersize to 1, it is quite likely that messages are buffered but never written to the database in your tests

Comment: if it is still not working: turn on internal debugging:
http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The issue was with the last parameter - In the DB the datatype is 'text' for that column and I was getting an exception when I enabled the trace:

> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Could not prepare database command [INSERT INTO [tblLogs] ([timeoccurred],[calltype],[severity],[message]) VALUES (@timeoccurred, @calltype, @severity, @message)]
>   System.InvalidOperationException: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size.

Finally I changed the parameter definition and provided the size explicitly and it worked..

```xml
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="1024"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

Thank you champs for your pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the connection string? :)

```
<connectionString value="XXX/>
```

If the connection string isnt the problem then put a breakpoint after your call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure` and inspect this variable

```
var loggers = log4net.LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers();
```

and check your loggers Appender is an ADONetAppender. If not, this means the previous call (Configure) hasnt found your config file.